# initialized constant RAILS_ROOT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Whilst following [these instructions](https://github.com/jeffp/wizardly-examples) to install wizardly-examples, I get the following error:

```
[wizardly-examples]$ rake gems:install
(in /Users/jason/Rails/wizardly-examples)
(eval):1: warning: already initialized constant RAILS_ROOT
rake aborted!
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
/Users/jason/Rails/wizardly-examples/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

Can anyone advise how to resolve the issue? Thank you

Comment: It appears wizardly does not yet work with Rails 3.

Comment: RAILS_ROOT is deprecated, now use Rails.root

Comment: Thanks, this solved THAT problem (I'm guessing) :) however, Wizardly still doesn't work with Rails 3 I have since found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be an out of date gem that's causing trouble. `rake gems:install` for one never worked properly, and has been eliminated in favor of:

```
bundle install
```

Rails 3 has switched to the [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) system by default. Older projects may still have the old task but it shouldn't be used. Since the `Rakefile` was often dependent on the very gems it was trying to install, you can see how it was a bad idea from the start.

In general if you're having trouble with `rake` tasks be sure to engage the `--trace` option to get a better idea of where it's going wrong.